# Deleting Table Entry In Django

Tags: django

So I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to make it so that the delete button deletes the entry from the form (and from the database as a whole). Attached below are my models and views.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Plant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="plant", null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    wateringInterval = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Plant
from .forms import AddNewPlant, RegisterForm

def home(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = AddNewPlant(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tempName = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            waterInt = form.cleaned_data["wateringInterval"]
            p = Plant(name = tempName,wateringInterval = waterInt)
            p.save()
            response.user.plant.add(p)

    else:
        form = AddNewPlant()
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form":form,})
```

Also, the template:

```
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
    <div class = "main">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Plant Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Water How Often?</th>
                <th scope="col">Next Watering</th>
                <th scope="col">Water</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for plant in user.plant.all %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                <td>{{plant.name}}</td>
                <td>{{plant.wateringInterval}}</td>
                <td>/</td>
                <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Water"/></td>
                <td><button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{plant}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As seen in the template, I know it needs to be a form and I tried to pass a value through the button that is the value of the current plant but I'm not sure how to proceed. I also have a second form on the same view that adds plants to the table.

Answer (score 0):

@Brandon Noll I think you need to decide if you would like to handle this delete operation from same view or make another view for it.

1. For option 1 you should pass if a hidden field to indicate it is delete request.

```
    def home(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        action = request.POST.get('action', '')
        if action == "":
          form = AddNewPlant(response.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              tempName = form.cleaned_data["name"]
              waterInt = form.cleaned_data["wateringInterval"]
              p = Plant(name = tempName,wateringInterval = waterInt)
              p.save()
              response.user.plant.add(p)
        elif action == "delete":
            # delete the object here
            id = request.POST.get('id', Flase)
            if id:
               Plant.objects.get(pk=id).delete()
    else:
        form = AddNewPlant()
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form":form,})
```

For deleting the object [itself use the queryset.delete() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete)

Comment: Definitely the first option.

Comment: @BrandonNoll Then you can use a hidden field name action. 
then set value to delete. In your code you can check if request.POST['action'] if it is delete or not. I am updating the answer to show you a sample of it.

Comment: What would the html look like and do I need to create a new form?

Comment: yes you just need a simple form with following field:
csrf token,   hidden field with action,   hidden field with id of the row object, and delete button will become type submit.